# Why cannot download pycharm package?

Tags: pycharm

I am trying to download a `PyCharm` package and this error occurred (see image below):

[image]

What do `cp949` and `UnicodeDecodeError` mean?

Comment: Try this search: *python unicodedecodeerror 'cp949' codec can't decode matplotlib* There are many results seems to be related with Chinese characters. Maybe you will find something heplful